Cafe vocabulary: Écureuil
I was at a café in a touristy part of Paris, and asked for a café noisette. The waitress told me that there was an old school term for this which is a écureuil. I have not been able to confirm this anywhere, in spite of looking quite hard. Is this for real, or was this an attempt to fool a tourist?

Never heard this one. Maybe kind of joke from the waitress (as noisettes and écureuils are related).

The waitress just made a joke.

I'm being told that a "café noisette" is not really a traditional french thing but something tourists may love (and think it's typically french haha).

@Frank Absolutely. French people rarely drink their coffee with milk, (except sometimes at breakfast at home, but not in cafés or restaurants), not even with a noisette of milk (noisette  here doesn't refer to the nut but to the quantity (TLF-B) of milk added to the coffee.  café noisette  ou  caffè macchiato c'est la même chose.

@None A nuage de lait and a noisette de beurre are common but a noisette de lait is a relatively modern and somewhat weird idiom.

@jlliagre Whatever... the colour of the mixture still depends on the quantity of milk added to the coffee.

I don't think café écureuil ever existed as an expression, outside maybe in some restaurants or cafés named L'écureuil or something.
Squirrels eat hazelnuts and also have the same kind of color in Europe (red squirrels) so there is some kind of link between them and the color of a café noisette.
That was certainly a joke. The waitress might also have challenged you about the pronunciation because écureuil is usually hard to pronounce for non-native French speakers.
Café noisette is recorded to refer to the color of the drink :


Gaston Esnault, Métaphores occidentales : essai sur les valeurs imaginatives concrètes du français parlé en Basse-Bretagne comparé avec les patois, parlers techniques et argots français, 1925.

Traditionally, to refer to the amount of milk added, the usual idiom was a nuage de lait. More recently, probably by analogy with a noisette de beurre, we've started to hear a noisette de lait even if it doesn't make a lot of sense.

In any case, café noisette is rarely a thing here. When a "non black" coffee is ordered in a bar or a restaurant, it's more often a café crème or a cappucino.

I can just imagine the same as a playful repartee in English. "Can I ave ze azelnut latte?" "Oh, we call that the Squirrel! ;)"
